# Base de datos phpMyAdmin subir a mi dominio

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos con phpMyAdmin, cuando lo utilizo con mi localhost funciona perfecto, pero si quiero subir la base de datos a mi dominio, como se cual es el host, usuario y contraseña?

Gracias

Comment: `phpMyAdmin`no es una base de datos, es un 'manejador' visual unicamente. El host sera la maquina donde vayas a instalarla y el usuario y contraseña los de esa maquina.

Comment: Que te refieres a maquina? Tengo un dominio con STRATO y quiero subirla a mi web, pero al subirla la información no me llega

Comment: Tener un dominio solo te da un nombre, para tener una bbdd tienes que tener tambien un servidor donde esten alojado tu software y la bbdd.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es subir tu base de datos a tu host, tiene que irte al apartado de base de datos, tu host te pedirá que definas nombre y contraseña de usuario que tendrá acceso a esa base de datos, esos son los que usaras para tu conexión.

En el apartado de host en tu archivo de conexión podrás dejar localhost, si es que tus archivos están almacenados en el mismo host, en caso de que desees hacer una conexión externa a tu base de datos tendrás que usar la ip de tu host.

Espero te sea de ayuda.